# Apache 2.4 - Have I been hacked?

Tags: apache-2.4

Whereas I didn't do anything on my dedicated server today, I realized that I couldn't PING it, the site was unreachable. So I checked the logs:

In about several hours appeared 153 000 lines of:

```
[Sat Nov 24 23:24:18.318257 2012] [authz_core:debug] [pid 21841:tid 140204006696704] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 80.8.82.242:62269] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: referer_url
[Sat Nov 24 23:24:18.318289 2012] [authz_core:debug] [pid 21841:tid 140204006696704] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 80.8.82.242:62269] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: referer_url
[Sat Nov 24 23:24:19.850212 2012] [authz_core:debug] [pid 21841:tid 140203989911296] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 80.8.82.242:62270] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: referer_url
```

Those log entries just appeared, even though I didn't do anything. In fact I show the logs at DEBUG level, before I had ever had these messages, now it appears every time.

Could someone explain why this has happened? Have I been hacked?

Comment: The log messages are from November 24. This seems way before your server was unreachable, right? And what do tools like `unhide` (man unhide; and you may have to install it) find? BTW, with debug messages, your logs can fill up fast.

Comment: Oh you are totally right... BTW, what can this be ? have you got any idea ?

Comment: i'm juste confuse for not having realised this... it's a production server in fact.. i hadn't an eye in the logs until now... as all the monitoring tools are installed and didn't told me anything...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me as normal log lines (for a debug level! Note that this is the most verbose level of logging) for access being granted to users. Do you have one or more password protected directories in your website? And is it possible that these directories were accessed 153000 times in the given time span?

Comment: I currently don't do any authentification...
As i make a grep in the configuration folders, it appears that the only files who deals with auth are :
conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf
conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

I just don't use authenfication in my actual configuration...

Comment: And you're the only one using it? And there's also no `.htaccess` file anywhere with any authorization configured?